# What could have blocked the launch of the screen inside the MIT App Inventor?

Tags: android, maps, apk, screen, app-inventor

With MIt App Inventor I'm building an app which contain 4 screen, and I got stacked launching one of them. It appears a pop-up saying

> *An internal error has occurred. Report a bug?*
>
> *Technical Data to be Submitted:*
>
> *notes = Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) > AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36*
>
> *foundIn = nb180*
>
> *faultData = java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException*
>
> *projectId = -1*

The app works on the phone, but in the mit app page I cannot access the screen anymore. Have anyone suggestions on how to resolve the issue?

I can share the .apk and .aia files.
Visit https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0xd4otgpuz4typ1/AAB5F013_N7q080L0RePRFzaa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I saw that polygons' visibility has to be true at the opening of the screen where they are, otherwise it will occour this kind of error; so I hid them after, during the initialization of the screen.